# Finding the maximum of three integers

Tags: functions

How can I prove this:

$$\max(a,b,c)=a+b+c-\min(a,b)-\min(a,c)-\min(b,c)+\min(a,b,c)$$

I checked it was true,but i dont know how to prove it.

Comment: What have you tried? How exactly did you check it? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1):

The equation is symmetric in $a,b,c$, so it suffices to check the case $a \ge b \ge c$.  Also, it holds for real numbers, not just integers.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the expression is symmetric so lets check $a\leq b\leq c$:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
a+b+c - (\min(a, b) + \min(a, c) + \min(b, c))+\min(a, b, c) & = a+b+c-a-a-b+a \\& = c\\ & = \max(a, b, c)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

As I typed this, @RobPratt wrote the same statement, his answer is also correct :)